# nasm segmentation fault while using arg

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, nasm, x86-64

```
extern puts
global main

section .text
main:
    mov rax, rdi
label:
    test rax, rax
    je exit
    push rsi
    mov rdi, [rsi]
    call puts
    pop rsi
    dec rax
    add rsi, 8
    jmp label
exit:
    pop rsi
    ret
```

I wrote nasm code like that. However segmentation fault occur in last. I can't understand why segmentation fault is occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rax` is not guaranteed to be preserved across function calls, as it is used to return integer results from functions (in the case of `puts` *"a nonnegative number on success, or EOF on error"*) You need to save the value of `rax` before calling `puts`, like you're doing with `rsi`, and restore it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you want to get the command line parameters in a GCC environment on a 64-bit Linux, where they are passed according to the GCC calling convention which follows the Linux calling convention "[System V AMD64 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI)".

Let's translate the program logic to C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if (argc != 0)
    {
        do
        {
            puts (*argv);
            argc--;
            argv++;
        } while (argc);
    }
    return;
}
```

The asm program doesn't return an exit code. That exit code should be in `RAX` when the function returns. BTW: `argc` is always >0 since the first string of `argv` holds the program name.

The `main` function is both "caller" (calls `puts`) and "callee" (returns to the GCC environment). As caller it has to preserve `RAX` and `RSI` before the call to `puts` and restore them when it needs them. A callee-saved register is not used. Don't forget to align the stack by 16.

This works:

```
extern puts
global main

section .text
main:                       ; RDI: argc, RSI: argv, stack is unaligned by 8
    mov rax, rdi
label:
    test rax, rax
    je exit
    push rbx                ; Push 8 bytes to align the stack before the call
    push rax                ; Save it (caller-saved)
    push rsi                ; Save it (caller-saved)
    mov rdi, [rsi]          ; Argument for puts
    call puts
    pop rsi                 ; Restore it
    pop rax                 ; Restore it
    pop rbx                 ; "Unalign" the stack
    dec rax
    add rsi, 8
    jmp label
exit:
;    pop rsi                ; Once too much
    xor eax, eax            ; RAX = 0 (return 0)
    ret                     ; RAX: return value
```